# Windows 10 deletes files without asking

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to install an application on windows 10: [Verge Wallet](https://github.com/vergecurrency/VERGE/releases/download/4.0.2/release_windows.zip)

And every time I unzip the file and run the app called Verge-QT Windows unceremoniously deletes the file without asking.

I went into the McAfee control panel and restored the file from Quarantine. But the next time I run it it just disappears again! Very frustrating. How do I get windows and mcafee to NOT delete programs I'm actively trying to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe stop Mcafee app before using it